# How do I unregister a directory as Git root?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, git-bash

I tried to push the project using git bash but I'd trouble understanding bunch of errors. I deleted the hidden **.git** file from project folder. Now Android Studio is showing this error message:

> Invalid VCS root mapping The directory  is registered as a
>   Git root, but no Git repositories were found there.

I want to git push directly from the Android Studio now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recreate you git repo again somehow. That hidden `.git` folder (no, it's not a file) is your git database. That's how git works. There's not server that maintains the state of you repo. Git is purely a disk based repository.

Installing new tools (like git bash or IntelliJ or SourceTree) don't create multiple different git databases for the same project. That `.git` folder is the **only** database shared by all git related tools.

You have several options:

1. You mentioned "push" so I'm going to assume there is a remote repository that you got your code from. If so you can just clone the repo again.

   If you want to save your current working files and try to push them again then you can clone to another directory and then copy all your files to the new repo. Git will notice the differences and you can then commit your files. You will lose your commit history but at least you will still have your latest changes.
2. Alternatively, you can clone to another directory and then move that .git folder to your current project. Git will not know that you moved that .git folder because from git's point of view that .git repository have suddenly gained a lot of uncommitted files.
3. If there is no remote repo or if you've just created a new empty remote repo (for example on github) then I'm sorry you've lost your entire commit history. Your only option is to start fresh with a `git init`

Comment: In some (advanced) cases *.git* **is** a file, but apparently here it's not the case.

Comment: I deleted the vcs.xml file which seemed to cause interruption probably. And started fresh! Thanks!